# Difference between grammar rules

Tags: grammar, computation-theory

Say there are two grammar rules

Rule 1   B -> aB | cB

and

Rule 2   B -> Ba | Bc

I'm a bit confused as the difference of these two. Would rule 1's expression be (a+c)* ? Then what would Rule 2's expression be?

Answer (score 1):

Both of those grammars yield the empty language since there is no non-recursive rule, so no sentence consisting only of terminals can be derived.

If you add the production `B→ε`, both grammars would yield the same language, equivalent to the regular expression `(a+c)*`. However, the parse trees produced by the parse would be quite different.